# Configuring implicit typing rules for Oracle

Tags: oracle, implicit-typing

Is it possible to configure the implicit typing rule in Oracle Server (at least version 10g) ?
If not a link to the documentation of the rules and how Oracle parameters impact the rules would be great.

For exemple when executing this query :

```
SELECT '' AS A FROM DUAL
```

Oracle will report that column A has `VARCHAR(0)` type on Oracle 10g and `VARCHAR(32)` on Oracle 9i.

Thanks

Comment: Actually, if you do
create view av as SELECT '' AS A FROM DUAL;
and select data_type, data_length from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'AV';
you should see both versions give the result as a CHAR(0).
If 9i is returning 32 characters, I'd suspect cursor sharing is set to forced

Comment: Gary you're right, the difference is due to the cursor sharing parameter ... I'd vote for your answer if you make a real one :)

This fixes the particular issue we are having right now but does not answer my more general question ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can be explicit, it will work with all versions of Oracle:

```
SQL> CREATE VIEW test AS SELECT CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR2(32)) var32 FROM DUAL;

View created

SQL> desc test
Name  Type         Nullable Default Comments 
----- ------------ -------- ------- -------- 
VAR32 VARCHAR2(32) Y
```

Comment: Yes we could but as we are migrating a big application this would have a very big impact on the code.

Answer (score 0):

As Gary says, the default datatype is CHAR....

```
SQL> create view v23 as select '' a from dual
  2  /

View created

SQL> desc a
Name               Null?    Type
------------------ -------- --------------- 
A                           CHAR
```

What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: We are migrating an application from Oracle 9i to Oracle 10g.

This difference in typing impacted our application so I thought this could be configurable somewhere in Oracle.
However as Gary pointed out, the difference seems to come from the cursor sharing parameter.
Thanks